# Yii2: What is a yii\web\IdentityInterface "Identity"?

Tags: yii2

I understand that it is an interface that is typically applied to your "User" model, but is that really its one and only true purpose?

The [official definition](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-identityinterface) found in Yii2 documentation is the following:

> IdentityInterface is the interface that should be implemented by a class providing identity information.

Alright, but before I can provide identity *information* I first need to know what an identity is.

Since there is no clear definition of what an "identity" is in the context of Yii, and the fact that the interface does not necessitate any sort of firstname/lastname information, it leads me to believe that it can be more than just an interface for your user model.

Could it also represent a company model (a group of users within a multi-tenant application) that you are signing into on behalf of as a user? What about a combination of user + company? Would that still be considered an identity? What is an identity, exactly?

Comment: I'm not very far either in Yii2 (in fact right to this point...) but what I think to understand is you have to set in your config the identityClass of the component you are using as for example:
 ‘components’ => [       
 ‘user’ => [            
‘identityClass’ => ‘dektrium\user\models\User’,......
And this class should implement the IdentityInterface which seems to me a minimum set of behaviors. For the rest it seems there no limitation of properties which could caracterize your identityClass. Hope it could help....

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE I know how to use it. What I need is a clearer definition of what an identity is.